# getElementById().disabled=true;

Tags: javascript, button, getelementbyid, disabled-control

I am trying to disable two icons when one is clicked. Then all the icons are active once it is clicked again. I can't figure this out for the life of me. Any suggestions.I am trying to disable two icons when one is clicked. Then all the icons are active once it is clicked again. I can't figure this out for the life of me. Any suggestions.

```
<!--SCRIPT-->
<script language="javascript">

function pic1() {
var img = document.getElementById('img').src;
if (img.indexOf('images/pages/financing.png')!=-1) {
document.getElementById('img').src  = 'images/pages/magnifying_glass.png';
document.getElementById('img2').disabled = true;
document.getElementById('img3').disabled = true;
document.getElementById("case").style.display='block';

}
else {
document.getElementById('img').src = 'images/pages/financing.png';
document.getElementById("case").style.display='none';
}

}

function pic2() {
var img = document.getElementById('img2').src;
if (img.indexOf('images/pages/check.png')!=-1) {
document.getElementById('img1').disabled = true;
document.getElementById('img3').disabled = true
document.getElementById('img2').src  = 'images/pages/magnifying_glass.png';"
}
else {
document.getElementById('img2').src = 'images/pages/check.png';
document.getElementById("case").style.display='none';
}

}

function pic3() {
var img = document.getElementById('img3').src;
if (img.indexOf('images/pages/pen.png')!=-1) {
document.getElementById('img1').disabled = true;
document.getElementById('img2').disabled = true
document.getElementById('img3').src  = 'images/pages/magnifying_glass.png';
}
else {
document.getElementById('img3').src = 'images/pages/pen.png';
document.getElementById("case").style.display='none';
}

}

</script>

<!--CONTENT-->

<div id="icons">
<li class="effect1"><img src="images/pages/financing.png" id="img"           onclick="pic1()"alt="" width="150px" height="150px"><br>FINANCING<p id="text"></p></li>
<li class="effect2"><img src="images/pages/check.png" id="img2" onclick="pic2()" alt=""        width="150px" height="150px"><br>FACTORS<p id="text2"></p></li>
<li class="effect3"><img src="images/pages/pen.png" id="img3" onclick="pic3()" alt=""     width="150px" height="150px"><br>LEASING<p id="text3"></p></li>

</div> <!-- end icons -->
```

Answer (score 3):

It looks like your first image has id "img" not "img1".